# Trouble understanding notation for function composition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am currently trying to create alternative formulations of group axioms but am having trouble understanding the notation used. The associativity axiom in my homework is formulated

*m*(*m* x *Id*)=*m*(*Id* x *m*)

where * is the typical symbol for function composition. What I do not understand is how the functions *m*x*Id* and *Id*x*m* act on group objects. *Id* is the identity functions *Id*(g)=g for all elements g in the group and *m* represents the multiplicative map for G.

Thank you

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication in a group $G$ is a function $m\colon G\times G\to G$.

Now, given two functions $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon C\to D$, you get a function sometimes denoted  $``f\times g”$, which is given by $f\times g\colon A\times C\to B\times D$ given by $(f\times g)(a,c) = (f(a),g(c))$.

So, think about associativity, which says that for all elements $a,b,c$ of $G$, you have $(ab)c = a(bc)$. Writing it in terms of the function $m$, we have that this says
$$m(m(a,b),c) = m(a,m(b,c)) \tag{1}.$$

From $m\colon G\times G\to G$ and $\mathrm{Id}\colon G\to G$, we get the function $(m\times \mathrm{Id})\colon (G\times G)\times G\to G\times G$ that sends $\Bigl((a,b),c\Bigr)$ to $(m(a,b),c)$. Which is the argument of $m$ on the left hand side of $(1)$ And you also get the function $\mathrm{Id}\times m\colon G\times(G\times G)\to G\times G$ that sends $\Bigl(a,(b,c)\Bigr)$ to $(a,m(b,c))$... which is the argument of $m$ on the right hand side of $(1)$.

So we can re-write $(1)$ by saying that $$m\Bigl(m\times\mathrm{Id}\bigl((a,b),c\bigr)\Bigr) = m\Bigl(\mathrm{Id}\times m\bigl(a,(b,c)\bigr)\Bigr)$$
for all $a,b,c\in G$. That is, you want the function
$m\circ\Bigl(m\times \mathrm{Id}\Bigr)$ to be equal to the function $m\circ\Bigl(\mathrm{Id}\times m\Bigr)$, or said another way,
$$m\bigl( m\times\mathrm{Id}\bigr) = m\bigl(\mathrm{Id}\times m\bigr),$$
the equation you have.